# Как искать информацию сразу на нескольких доменах

Tags: поиск, поисковые-системы

Я знаю что можно найти информацию в поисковике по определенному сайту с помощью ключа site

К примеру:
`Name Lastname site:vk.com`

Но как выглядит запрос, чтобы информация искалась сразу на нескольких доменах ?

К сожалению данный метод не выдаёт результатов:
`Name Lastname site:vk.com site:facebook.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью *pipe* оператора:

```
[информация которую ищем] site:snapchat.com | site:facebook.com
```

Либо с помощью `OR`:

```
[информация которую ищем] site:snapchat.com OR site:facebook.com
```

Comment: Похожий вопрос был также найден [тут](https://superuser.com/questions/550026/how-to-search-within-specific-websites-at-once)